# TeX capacity exceeded when using mdframed inside figure

Tags: floats, mdframed

Sorry if this question has already been answered before. The following code always produce the silly error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].<write>Package \mdframedpackagename Info: Not enough space on this page\on... \end{mdframed}
```

I have reduced it to the following example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[6]

%\newpage

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{mdframed}[rightmargin=+0.5cm, leftmargin=+0.5cm]
hello world
\end{mdframed}
\caption{Some FOOBAR}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Once I include the newpage command, the example compiles just fine!

I'm using this version of MiKTeX:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2011.6.14) 7 JAN 2014 17:13
entering extended mode
**test.tex
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get no error. On the other hand, I advise against using `[H]`.

Comment: Everything is fine here using This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)

Comment: Ok, I just checked and the problem occurs also without [H]. Unfortunately I cannot simply update my MiKTeX as I am currently working on a university computer.

Comment: Try to remove the trash text. I guess that it is related with it.

Comment: The trash text is to simulate a quite full page. It only happens consistently when the preceding page is almost full. And yes, it does not happen without, sorry I should have made my intention of the minimal example clearer.

Comment: Try to use another package to produce the text. `lipsum` and then use as `\lipsum[1-4]` for example.

Comment: No problem here either. Is your TeX distribution up to date?

Comment: Daniel, I do of course not know, how strict the admins on your university are, but usually in your user area you can install a full MiKTeX, too (not admin, but user installation!). Or is it a pool computer with user area on a net drive, and also the size is restricted? On the other hand they _have to_ keep the system wide installation up to date, it’s their job. Go and keep nag them, if it is not. Beside this: You also can add a [local tree for MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69483), where you only install some packages, e.g. an updated `mdframed`.

Comment: It works fine for me with latest XeTeX under miktex.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's unreproducible with current packages and likely caused by outdated ones.